# Java library for database backed collections

Tags: java, sql, database, collections, orm

I am looking for an efficient sql backed collections library, for the Java programming language.

I need to do database manipulations that fit very well the Collections API, is there something that can be a good bridge for that, or must I roll my own thing.

Comment: I'm going to stick my neck out here and say that I found doing this type of thing seamlessly (e.g. with Hibernate) is fraught with its own set of problems and I now use bespoke DAO implementations (based on Spring JDBC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

err.. isn't what you are describing [hibernate](http://hibernate.org) or any JPA implementation?

It's pretty efficient and models all results and associations using implementations of the java collections API.